# Empty String Error While reading and writing CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I am reading the csv file and writing it to Database ussing prepare statement but while inserting the number column ,i am getting this error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

i tried to handle by this way

```
if(csvLength > 43 && (null != csvRead[43] && !csvRead[43].trim().equals("\"\""))){

        pstmt.setFloat(45,Float.parseFloat((csvRead[43].replac("\"","")).toString()));
        }else{

        pstmt.setNull(45,Types.INTEGER);
```

but still giving the same error .Please help

the value at csvRead[43] - """"

Comment: print value of `csvRead[43]`, then value of `csvRead[43].replace("\"","")` and then see where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `!csvRead[43].trim().equals("\"\"")` is returning true, it is going inside if condition and trying yo parse `""` and you are getting NumberFormatException. It should be `!csvRead[43].trim().equals("")`.

Also I would like to suggest, create a variable for `csvRead[43]`, you are reading thrice a value from a array. That will improve performance a bit.

```
if(csvLength > 43 && (null != csvRead[43] && !csvRead[43].trim().equals(""))){

        pstmt.setFloat(45,Float.parseFloat((csvRead[43].replace("\"\"","0")).toString()));
        }else{

        pstmt.setNull(45,Types.INTEGER);
}
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but still got the same error

Comment: Ok. Whay `pstmt.setNull(45,Types.INTEGER);` ?

Comment: Print `csvRead[43]` before if statement to see, what is the value in it.

Comment: pstmt.setNull(45,Types.INTEGER); it becasue datatype in DB is number and condition is if there is no value in CSV file then set null in db

Comment: Try updated code above, if you are getting `""""` ("\"\"") value, then you need to replace it with `0`

Answer (score 0):

This does not check for an empty string:

```
trim().equals("\"\"")
```

That checks for a string whose value is two quotes. You need to check for `equals("")`

Comment: i tried your suggestion but still got the same error